# wkhtmltopdf-binary not being found on development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

Testing on localhost is running wicked-pdf gem output as expected.  It has a dependency to wkhtmltopdf.

As per the [indications here](https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem) I determined and verified the existence on the Ubuntu 18.04 development server of this directory:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.5.4/bin
```

then changed access rights

```
chmod -R 777 ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.5.4/bin
```

Yes, `bundle install` returns

```
Using wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.12.5.4
```

`which wkhtmltopdf`  returns

```
/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf
```

While the [wickedPDF gem instructions](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)  encourages to create an initializer.  However directory `/usr/local/bin/`  only has two documents in it : bundle and bundler.  So I am clueless as to what is going on...

Still accessing an action calling a `.pdf` extension returns the error

```
RuntimeError in [class]Controller#pdf
Location of wkhtmltopdf unknown
```

how can wkhtmltopdf be properly accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the elements of solution were in the question.

One forgotten element was that the server was multiuser and wkhtmltopdf was originally installed by another user. As the [wkhtmltopdf gem page states](https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem), there is a permissions issue during installation; it is then observed that those permissions were assigned to the other user.

As per link to wicked PDF gem, creating an initializer containing:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

solved the issue.